# Using Content Delivery Network (CDN) hosting is better than host files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-hosting, cdn

I'm developing web solution from a while and I've the feeling that most developers uses CDN links for sources rather than host JavaScript libraries or CSS styles files besides their pages.
Is it just a reason of space or are there any other reasons such as speed or anything else?

If CDNs are faster, how can it be possible that calling through an external link is faster than a local file on the same hosting?

I'd like to receive evidences of the pros and cons of CDNs, I am not asking for not opinion answers or preferences.

Comment: Imagine your webpage it's hosted in China, and someone accesses your webpage from EEUU, the assets will be retrieved from China to EEUU.  On the other hand, the CDN service has a world-wide infrastructure for optimizing access according to the location of a user.  Therefore, CDN services are a better choice for assets.

Comment: Any question that comes down to personal preference is off-topic for SO. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Comment: Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network should illuminate quite a bit on the reasons why they're commonly used. TL;DR: They have locations closer to users, which reduces latency, and using a shared CDN for libraries means a lot of your users will already have it cached from visiting some other site.

Comment: Perhaps because if you make some research and understand what CDN really is you would not ask this question in here. Nevertheless I think that as long as it is not a repeated question, all questions have their value... so, personally I wouldn’t downvote yours.

Comment: the downvote tooltip says: *This question does not show any research effort; ...* .. I am pretty sure there is a ton of articles in the net talking about this

Comment: I am asking evidences of that, so why u put on hold for "opinion-based"? I am asking for not opinion answers! @Ele

Answer (score 2):

The reason for hosting files like that on a CDN is exactly the same as why you'd host any file on a CDN. A CDN has many nodes placed around the world that are likely to be much closer to an end user than your one web server. If somebody in Australia requests your website that's hosted in London you're going to have to send everything to them.

Alternatively you can host only the files you own, and leave the rest to a CDN. The CDN files are retrieved from a node closer to the user and your server only has to deal with your files. This reduces latency to your site and increases the chance that, if you're using a widely used library, a user might already have it cached.